# How to exclude particular values in a extjs store

Tags: javascript, extjs

THe following code is my extjs store. I would like to exclude some particular value from this store.

For example the value such as "option 1", "option 2" would be exclude from the store, or when I retrieve this store and display in the input dropdown field.

How can I do it?

Thank you.

```
 var input1store = new Ext.data.Store({
fields: [{name: 'name'}],
proxy:{
    type: 'ajax',
    url:    'www.requesturl.com?format=json&source1',
            reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root:   'xml.result'
    }
},
autoLoad:false,
sorters:    [{property: 'name', direction: 'asc'}]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a filter http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filter

```
var input1store = new Ext.data.Store({
    fields: [{name: 'name'}],
    proxy:{
        type: 'ajax',
        url:    'www.requesturl.com?format=json&source1',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root:   'xml.result'
        }
    },
    autoLoad:false,
    sorters:    [{property: 'name', direction: 'asc'}],

    listeners: { 
       load: function() {
           this.filter(function(rec){
               var val = rec.get('name');
               return val != 'option1' && val != 'option2';
           });
       }
    }
});
```